# Pass integer to running thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem in Java with threads. I am trying to pass an integer from the mainthread to another running thread in Java - but the value is always 0. Is there a way to solve this? I guess the reason why this happends is that threads have their own lives.

Here is the class that receives the integer - via an accessor-method. Then its supposed to be printed in the print-method - but as I mentioned, the value is ZERO.

```
  class MyThread implements Runnable {


     private int val;

     public void run() {

         printVal();
     }

     public void setValue(int val) {
         this.val = val;
     }

     private void printVal() {

             while (true) {
                 System.out.println("val: " + this.val);

             try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
             } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

             }
         }
     }  
   }
```

Comment: look up `volatile`... for starters.

Comment: Also, while this may be obvious; be sure you are actually calling `setValue()` when you think you are, with the value you think you are calling it with. There's always a possibility that you have a logic error elsewhere. Adding a temporary print-out in `setValue()` could help you spot errors along those lines.

Comment: Where is your `printVal()` method defined? I can see only `print()`...

Comment: @Katona I have fixed that

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you  got an obstacle made by cached value of variable. To solve it, please declare your `int` as [volatile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml)

```
private volatile int mainVal;
```

so that `int` will not be cached. Now you can pass it to other threads without cache effect.

Comment: please provide more code in your question how you use it

Comment: @user2365568 Then it sounds like you may not be calling `setValue()` when you think you are (I just left a question comment about this). Please post the rest of your code.